# Custom Navigation Items Not Being Displayed on Top Level View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have a project where I have TableViewCells push to different View Controllers. In this project, I use custom navigation controllers. This is the code of the navigation controller in the first view controller:

```
//Design of Header
        let nav_background = UIImage(named: "header_background")
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(nav_background, for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.16
        navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.shadowRadius = 10

        let account = UIImage(named: "header_account")
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: account)
        let blankView = UIImageView()
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -3, height: 3)
        imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.16
        imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 10
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem?.customView = imageView
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.leftBarButtonItem?.customView = blankView
```

The first view controller only displays the custom background and no other properties.

This is the code of the second view controller which is loaded when a cell in the TableView is selected:

```
//Design of Header
        let account = UIImage(named: "header_account")
        let accountView = UIImageView(image: account)
        let back = UIImage(named: "header_backarrow")
        let backView = UIImageView(image: back)
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.customView = backView
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.customView = accountView
```

Theoretically, everything should be replaced with the code written here and the titles listed in the View Controller's properties(This works for all view controllers except the first one.) I am taking all this directly off of the Apple webpage: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller

Here are the exact paragraphs I am referencing:

Left Item:

> If the new top-level view controller has a custom left bar button item, that item is displayed. To specify a custom left bar button item, set the leftBarButtonItem property of the view controller’s navigation item.

Middle Item:

> If no custom title view is set, the navigation bar displays a label containing the view controller’s default title. The string for this label is usually obtained from the title property of the view controller itself. If you want to display a different title than the one associated with the view controller, set the title property of the view controller’s navigation item instead.

Right Item:

> If the new top-level view controller has a custom right bar button item, that item is displayed. To specify a custom right bar button item, set the rightBarButtonItem property of the view controller’s navigation item.

Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: The proper way is to set, for example, `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = ...` in a view controller's `viewDidLoad`. Then when the view controller is shown in a navigation controller, the nav bar will automatically show the view controllers navigation items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because `customView` is `nil` in most cases.

If you want to set a navigation item to a `UIImage`, create a new `UIBarButtonItem` from the image, and then assign the bar button item.

For example, from a `UIImage`:

```
let accountItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: account, style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = accountItem
```

To create one from a custom view, use:

```
let accountItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: imageView)
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = accountItem
```

Please note that this can still fail if `navigationController` is nil or if `topItem` is nil.